# How to get html page of a website using TCP socket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I have tried to send HTTP requests through TCP by connecting to a site, but I don't get any reply in return when I try to receive data from the server .

Here's my code in Python:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket() ; 
s.connect(('google.com' , 80)) ; 
s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n") ; 
s.recv(1024) # The program waits here infinitely meaning I haven't got a reploy from server.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the html page using a TCP or UDP socket?

Also, since HTTP is connectionless, does it mean I should only use UDP and not TCP?

Comment: what's up with the semicolons?

Comment: HTTP is **stateless**, not **connectionless**. BIG difference. HTTP doesn't maintain any state information between requests (if a server wants that, it needs to use cookies or localstorage). Multiple HTTP requests can be sent over a single connection, or separate connections. HTTP doesn't work over UDP, you must use TCP.

Comment: Thank you , that cleared a lot